# 18F45K22 - interrupção externa

Tags: c, longpolling, microcontrolador

Um led fica piscando a cada meio segundo, enquanto o outro só sera acesso quando eu mandar um sinal de nível baixo para RB0 no microcontrolador, queria saber se falta configurar alguma coisa, pois fiz exatamente como me pediram e mesmo assim, apenas o led por polling fica piscando, a interrupção não ocorre: segue abaixo o código em C:

```
bit  controle;
void interrupt()      
{
  if(INT0IF_bit)
  {
    controle = ~controle;
    INT0IF_bit = 0;
    if(controle) RA0_bit = 1;
    else RA0_bit = 0;
  }
}

void main()
{
  TRISA = 0xFC; 
  TRISB = 0xFF; 
  PORTA = 0xFC;
  PORTB = 0xFF;
  IPEN_bit = 1; 
  RBIP_bit = 1;
  INTCON = 0x90; 
  INTCON2 = 0x00;
  controle = 0;

  while(1)
  {    
    //  Lógica para fazer LEd piscar por Polling..
    RA1_bit = 0x01;
    delay_ms(TempoPolling);
    RA1_bit = 0x00;
    delay_ms(TempoPolling);
    // Fim da Lógica
}
```